# What is the difference between the inventions in US 2015/0291122 A1 and WO 2012/113362 A1?

Tags: us20150291122

In reference to the patent: [US20150291122](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150291122)

It seems very simillar to https://www.google.ch/patents/WO2012113362A1?cl=en, what is the specific difference.

Comment: What has your own research turned up?

Comment: One similarity is neither is a patent yet.

Answer (score 1):

WO2012113362 has been granted as [EP2678191B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2678191B1/en). US20150291122, I believe, is still just an application. My cursory examination indeed suggests that EP2678191B1 is significant prior art for US20150281122 as the main concept as far as I can see is very similar. EP2678191B1's claims are pretty narrow so there might even be further prior art.